# Reading dynamic components props (from parent component to child)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a react-redux application, and I'm trying to do the following.

1. putting form component inside a modal.
2. firing the submit from the modal.
3. make it all generic and dynamic.

this is my modal (you can see the ObjectForm inside):

```
       <Modal show={showAddObjectModal} onHide={:: this.close}>
            <Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Title>Add Object</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <Grid>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <ObjectFrom formClass={currentClassName} formId={this.state.compId}/>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button onClick={:: this.close}>Close</Button>
                <Button bsStyle='primary' onClick={:: this.submitForm}>Save changes</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
```

In the form component inside the modal I'm using "formId" prop. the form component handles the submit action, and it can be invoked internally from a button inside the form or externally from the parent component (that was done for UI/UX consideration), so it would look something like this:

[form inside modal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC7mW.png)

My goal is to create dynamic unique form Id (using createUniqueId function) for every instance. Each form that is create will be save in the App store in a forms array with its unique Id and with its submit status (true/false). When dispatching a submit action (from anywhere, parent, form it self), the submit state will change to true and will be checked by the form component. if true, the form will handle the submit and post the data to the server.

In order to set the form Id, the form checks if a formId was set (check if the prop has value) outside by the parent component. If it was set, then this is the formId, if not the form generate its own form Id.

this function checks if the parent sent formId via the prop "formId":

```
addFormId(props){
    let formId = null;

    //check if formId was passed from parent using props
    if (!props.formId) {
        formId = GetUniqeComponentId();
    } else {
        formId = props.formId;
    }

    console.log('add form id',formId);
    //update the component's state
    this.setState({formId});

    let {dispatch}=this.props;
    if(formId!=null) dispatch(actions.setForm(formId));

}
```

My problem is that I can't set the formId from the parent modal since in the fraction of time when it is created, and until the parent generates the unique id, the value of the parent formId prop is null, and the form "thinks" that there is no parent form Id value, so it generates its own.

thanks :)

Comment: Do all the form only have ACL, Price, Name, picture?

Comment: yes these are the form fields, but this is only for the current case, they maybe other fields.

Comment: My doubt is, will the fields in the each form will be dynamic?